# Magento: redirect to select payment method

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on a custom payment method for magento. In case of errore during the "place the order phase" I would like to redirect the user to "Payment Information" (i.e. the part of the ceckout process during which the user selects the payment method).

Is there any way to achieve this and output any possible error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if by "place order" you mean the final process, which means "save order".

I suppose you put these lines in your main payment model.

```
    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl(){
    return Mage::getUrl('yourmodule/yourcontroller/yourmethod');
}

In yourmethod, deal with exceptions (search by 'try catch - php').. and when you get one of these exceptions, redirect to your onestep page.

Unfortunelly, at this point (onestep) page, i don't know exactly how you can focus on payment method. But , just take a look at the calls in that phase that you can figure it out.
```